# How to select one record from a SELECT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am running the follwoing SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES WHERE USERTYPE = 'PREMIUM' ORDER BY SALES DESC;
```

The output of this query yields a list of countries.

Now I need to populate a field in another table which is like TOP_SALES_COUNTRY, SECOND_TOP_SALES_COUNTRY and THRID_TOP_SALES_COUNTRY for which I only need the first,second and third records in the output of this SELECT statement. Kindly advise on how this can be achieved.

Comment: why not just `SELECT ... LIMIT 3`? You can't really collapse a 3 row result into a 3 column 1 row insert easily. but doing the limit query, fetching the results, then doing a 3-field insert would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Marc B. LIMIT 3 was a nice option. But how do I construct a query to INSERT into 3 different fields as mentioned above after executing this SELECT query. I am doing this in script. Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: Got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422529/mysql-how-do-you-insert-into-a-table-with-a-select-subquery-returning-multiple-r

Comment: So I tried INSERT INTO TABLE_1(TOP_SALES_COUNTRY,SECOND_TOP_SALES_COUNTRY,THIRD_TOP_SALES_COUNTRY) VALUES (SELECT COUNTRY FROM COUNTRIES WHERE USERTYPE = 'PREMIUM' ORDER BY SALES DESC LIMIT 3) and it didn't work. Kindly advise

Comment: I have added more ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use any of the following:
**Option 1:**

```
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)
FROM table_name;
```

**Option 2:**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
LIMIT number;
```

**Option 3:**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE ROWNUM <= number;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES WHERE USERTYPE = 'PREMIUM' ORDER BY SALES DESC limit 0,1;` to get the first row

Comment: how does this retrieve the top 3 rows ?

Comment: @BWS it doesn't, it retrieves the top row, obvious changes needed to retrieve the top 3

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is a modification of reverse_engineer's answer. FOr example to get 2nd top most country i used LIMIT 1,1 and for third value I used LIMIT 2,1. Thank you for your help. Immensely grateful to all.

Comment: I have added some more ways to do it.