# How to use SELECT with INSERT subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
SELECT IF (I don't get NULL, "pass", null)
FROM(
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value)
)
```

If the insert is successful, it will not return anything, so this query returns null. If the insert is successful, I will get "pass" instead of a value.

I don't know how to do this. I'm thinking a stored procedure can do it, but I also think that it's not necessary.

Edit:
I've so far tried this, though:

```
INSERT INTO `permissions` VALUES (7,"test",null);

SELECT IF(`p_id` IS NOT NULL, "pass", null ) `p_id`
FROM `permissions`
WHERE `p_id` = 7;
```

Where 7 is user-defined. This one works as I want it to. It's not a stored procedure, but it's two queries. I want to know if it's possible to do this with just one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MySQL `INSERT` statement doesn't return a resultset; so it can't be used a row source for a query. If the `INSERT` statement fails, it will throw an error.

To return a resultset, a separate `SELECT` statement would need to be executed.

These two statements could be executed in the context of a stored procedure, if the goal is to execute a single database call.

**EDIT:**

**Q:** I want to know if it's possible to do this with just one query?

**A:** No, it's not possible with just one statement. You'd need two statements: an `INSERT` statement (to perform the insert operation) and an `SELECT` statement (to return a result).

To do this in a single database call, you'd need a MySQL stored program that performs the two statements: first, the INSERT, and catch errors thrown (with a `CONTINUE HANDLER`), and then a `SELECT` to return a resultset.

It's not clear why you need a resultset that returns a column containing `'PASS'` or `NULL`.

The normative pattern would be to run the `INSERT` statement, check to see whether it threw an error,  and/or check "affected rows" using function available in the client library, and/or run a separate `SELECT` statement to retrieve the value from the MySQL `ROW_COUNT()` function, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES ('myval') ;
SELECT IF(ROW_COUNT(),'PASS',NULL) ;
```

(To do this within a stored procedure, you'd need to define a `CONTINUE HANDLER` in the procedure to "catch" errors from the `INSERT` so that the procedure will continue running (rather than throwing an error) so the `SELECT` statement will be run.)

Comment: Can I write a stored procedure that throws "pass" if the insert is successful, or null if not? (obviously, yes, but I mean, elegantly)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted ??

```
INSERT INTO table1
(
 column1,
 column2,
)
VALUES
(
 (
   SELECT column
   FROM table2 
   JOIN table3 ON condition
 ),

 (
  "a string"
 ),
);
```

See the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422529/mysql-how-do-you-insert-into-a-table-with-a-select-subquery-returning-multiple-r)

Comment: This replicates one table's data into another, right? I just want to throw a "pass" result if the preceding insert statement was successful.