# How to loop insert in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to batch insert into `roles` table below SQL to initialize user's role information, I grant three `roles` to every `user`:

```
INSERT INTO `roles` 
(`role_id`, `role_name`, `menu_id`, `role_updated_time`, `role_created_time`, `role_creator_user_id`, `role_sys_type`) 
VALUES  
(40, 'developer', '[1,2,3,4]', NULL, now(), 1027, 1),   
(41, 'financial', '[1,2,3]', NULL, now(), 1027, 2),     
(42, 'operation', '[1,2]', NULL, now(), 1027, 3);
```

I want to do this job in one SQL, so how to `foreach` every `usr_id` in `users` table so that it insert in `roles` table, the `usr_id` is equivalent to `role_creator_user_id` in `roles` table, and the `role_id` is `auto_increment`.

I use this SQL but not work:

```
INSERT INTO `roles` 
    (`role_id`, `role_name`, `menu_id`, `role_updated_time`, `role_created_time`, `role_creator_user_id`, `role_sys_type`) 
    VALUES  
    (40, 'developer', '[1,2,3,4]', NULL, now(), (select usr_id from users), 1),     
    (41, 'financial', '[1,2,3]', NULL, now(), (select usr_id from users), 2),   
    (42, 'operation', '[1,2]', NULL, now(), (select usr_id from users), 3);
```

So I tried this, also not work:

> INSERT INTO `roles` 
>           (`role_id`, `role_name`, `menu_id`, `role_updated_time`, `role_created_time`, `role_creator_user_id`, `role_sys_type`)
>           VALUES
>           (select 100, 'developer','[1,2,3,4]',NULL,now(),usr_id,1 from users)

Comment: I assume that "select usr_id from users" will return more than one entry. That might be the problem with your first variation, because in that statement you really just want one value. For the second version, try INSERT INTO `roles` 
    (`role_id`, `role_name`, `menu_id`, `role_updated_time`, `role_created_time`, `role_creator_user_id`, `role_sys_type`)
    select 100, 'developer','[1,2,3,4]',NULL,now(),usr_id,1 from users

Comment: @igorshmigor You mean remove the bracket? I tried, not work

Comment: It worked here on my database. What error do you get? Maybe some of the values are inconsistent with the table structure? Did you also remove the "Values" keyword? Because you have to remove that too, not just the brackets.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422529/mysql-how-do-you-insert-into-a-table-with-a-select-subquery-returning-multiple-r . It's just INSERT [...] SELECT [..], no VALUES

Comment: @igorshmigor Yes, you are right, when I remove the `Values` keyword it works! Thank you!