# Need INSERT query modified to accomdate multiple values

Tags: mysql

Current syntax:

```
insert into log_file 
(
    table_id, 
    text, 
    today_date,
    user_id
) 
values 
(
(select id from table where table_no in ('Table1','Table2')),
"Some Text Now",
now(),
143
);
```

Of course I get the error 'ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row'

How can I accomdate this without having to write out a lot of individual queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL How do you INSERT INTO a table with a SELECT subquery returning multiple rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422529/mysql-how-do-you-insert-into-a-table-with-a-select-subquery-returning-multiple-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a subquery, you can use the [INSERT...SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
insert into log_file (table_id, text, today_date, user_id)
select id, "Some Text Now", now(), 143
from table
where table_no in ('Table1','Table2')
```