# How to change the data of a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to change some data of one column from `table1` and then, I will copy some of the `table1` data to `new_table`, here is my example tables.

**table1**

```
id | url | user1_ign | user2_ign | message | fields that are not needed anymore
```

**new_table**

```
id | url | user1_ign | user2_ign | message
```

Basically, `table1` have fields that are not in `new_table`. My problem is I do not know how to change the data in a field while copying it to a new table (already searched here).

I need to change the data of the `url`. Here is the layout.

**table1**

```
id | url        | user1_ign | user2_ign | message     | some field

1  | jj-HasZNsh | jj        | gg        | hello dude! | ...
```

**new_table**

```
id | url           | user1_ign | user2_ign | message

1  | jj-gg-HasZNsh | jj        | gg        | hello dude!
```

That is what I needed to do to, as you can see, I need to change the url in **new_table** based on the `user1_ign` and `user2_ign`. Is there a way of how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I have this kind of `url` in **table1** `number-HasZNsh` or `alphabet-HasZNsh`.

I need them to become like this in **new_table**

- `number-HasZNsh` -> `ign1-ign2-HasZNsh`
- `alphabet-HasZNsh` -> `ign1-ign2-HasZNsh`

This is what I need to do specifically.

Comment: Regarding your modification, I would suggest you look into [SPLIT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2696901/3504007). Once the stored procedure is installed on the server, you can use it like any other command as illustrated in that solution. For your situation, it's really just tweaking the `REPLACE(url ......)` line in my solution to your taste.

Comment: yes your solution is great, I just dont know how to make the hash in the url still in there.

Comment: If the above stored procedure is installed, you can do `CONCAT(ign1, '-', ign2, '-', SPLIT(url, '-', 2)) \`url\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the `INSERT` statement for your destination table followed `SELECT` to set the values to be inserted. For your `url` field as you specify above, you can use `REPLACE` to replace a string inside a string.

```
INSERT INTO 
   `new_table` (id, url, user1_ign, user2_ign, message)
SELECT
   id, 
   REPLACE(url, '-', '-gg-') `url`,
   user1_ign,
   message
FROM 
   `table1`
```

If you wish to grab data from another field for the `gg` part of the `REPLACE` line, you would use :

```
INSERT INTO 
   `new_table` (id, url, user1_ign, user2_ign, message)
SELECT
   id, 
   REPLACE(url, '-', CONCAT('-', user2_ign, '-') `url`,
   user1_ign,
   message
FROM 
   `table1`
```

For more information on the command syntax as used above :

- [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
- [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [INSERT INTO table1 FROM table2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422561/3504007)

Comment: I think -gg- is not hardcoded but based on the user2_ign column

Comment: @barudo if that is the case, he can replace `REPLACE(url, '-', '-gg-') \`url\`` with `REPLACE(url, '-', CONCAT('-', user1_ign, '-') \`url\``

Comment: what is the `url` inside of the `REPLACE` ? is that the column name itself?

Comment: @DumbQuestion yes, that is the column name itself.  Between `SELECT` and `FROM` are the columns selected.  You can transform data using other SQL commands in there as I did with `REPLACE` and in the last comment `CONCAT`. This example also assumes that the field types and sizes in `\`new_table\`` are sufficient for the data being copied/transformed.

Comment: uhm, I think you missed a close bracket `)` for REPLACE ? where do I need to put it? before `url` ?

Comment: In the comment, yes, missing a bracket, but in the example solution, no bracket is missing.  Will put into solution the alternative

Comment: uhm I have a little problem regarding with changing the url, I have this old url `228-HasZNsh` and what I need the url to become is `ign1-ign2-HasZNsh`. `ign1` and `ign2` is a string. I tried to remove the url inside the `REPLACE` but it gives me an error.