# Inserting rows in one table with values from another table in a loop with MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, database-trigger

I need to set up a trigger in MariaDB 10.1 which inserts rows in another table. So far the trigger looks like this for a single record:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER generate_items
    AFTER INSERT
    ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- some_id is the id from my_table
    INSERT INTO another_table(some_id, some_value)
    VALUES (NEW.id, 'x');
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

My problem is that `some_value` is not the only record to be inserted but a list of values fetched from another table. Actually I would need something like this in the trigger:

```
-- Pseudo-code for illustrating
SET @values = SELECT value FROM some_table WHERE condition = true;
FOREACH(@value in @values) DO
  INSERT INTO another_table(some_id, some_value) VALUES (NEW.id, @value);
END
```

Which possibilities would I have with MariaDB 10.1? I read that MariaDB 10.3 offers a FOR-loop but we cannot upgrade the database yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL How do you INSERT INTO a table with a SELECT subquery returning multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422529).  You should *not* need a "for loop". You should be able to use " insert into ..select.." syntax instead, per the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `insert ... select` syntax instead of `insert ... values()`. So something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER generate_items
    AFTER INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO another_table(some_id, some_value)
    SELECT NEW.id, value FROM some_table WHERE condition = true
;
```

This will insert as many records in `another_table` as there are in `some_table` for the given conditions, retrieving `value` from the query while assigning the same `NEW.id` to every record.

Side note: since the trigger is made of a single query, there is no need to use `BEGIN` and `END`, nor to change the delimiter. The above simplified version should just work.