# How to insert data with subquery using SELECT * as VALUE?

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-insert

I have 2 queries.
First query is

```
SELECT date 
FROM tableA 
WHERE 
    db='mydb' AND 
    date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableB WHERE db='mydb') 
LIMIT 1;
```

Second query is

```
INSERT INTO tableB (date, db, comment) 
SELECT * FROM tableA 
WHERE 
    db = 'mydb' AND 
    date = (date that i got from first query);
```

Data types are:
`db(VARCHAR), date(date), comment(mediumblob)`.

statement `SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE db = 'mydb' AND date = (date that i got from first query);` returns exactly 1 row, but somehow second query returns that `1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

I have tried to change `SELECT *` statement to each columns, but it didn't work on column `comment`. And it is impossible to do this on trigger because tableA is in system table.

Comment: `WHERE db='mydb'` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: in first query you are aggregating, so you get 1 row, there can be multiple records matching for the same date, so you might get multiple records in your second query.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422529/mysql-how-do-you-insert-into-a-table-with-a-select-subquery-returning-multiple-r/9422561)?

Comment: @GROVER. I was trying to clone mysql query log to my database. the clause ```db = 'mydb'``` is to filter that mysql just take queries on my database

Comment: @PSK no, the dates are all unique. date format is Y-m-d H:i:s and inserted automatically by mysql. I'm sure the dates are unique

Comment: @Kyle_697 I have read that before. but i don't think it solve my problem

Comment: Simple: Never use `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the goal, you are trying to copy all fresh values from A to B. Here "fresh" means "date not exists in the target table yet".
I think it can be simplified to this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO `tableB` (`date`, `db`, `comment`) 
SELECT `date`, `db`, `comment` 
FROM `tableA` 
WHERE `db` = 'mydb' 
AND `date` > (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM `tableB` WHERE `db` = 'mydb')
```

Comment: Thanks @artoodeeto, I use this query in firs time i build the program. But it returns error when i insert column `comment`. the data type is mediumblob, filled with multiple ```"``` and it crashes the query unless i use ```*```

Comment: Please don't use * here. Use exact field list and the same field order on both insert and select clauses. It should not crash if you have compatible data types on fields.