# Inserting Multiple Rows in MySQL Easily?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm having a bit of trouble. I need to award an item to users on our site, but I don't want to manually fill in the numbers one by one. Is there a way to set the SQL query to `INSERT INTO` from `UID 9 to 5430` without having to create multiple lines? Here's my example.

```
INSERT INTO `item_owned` (`id`, `uid`, `iid`, `kind`, `time_owned`, `notes`) VALUES (NULL, 'x', '3626', '1', '1592596732', 'NotBanned')
```

I'm trying to have the "x" be a number, but to have MYSQL generate multiple numbers from 9 to 5430 without having to generate multiple numbers/code all at once. So something like:

```
INSERT INTO `item_owned` (`id`, `uid`, `iid`, `kind`, `time_owned`, `notes`) VALUES (NULL, '9 - 5430', '3626', '1', '1592596732', 'NotBanned')
```

The `9 - 5430` is where the issue is. I want to award the item to everyone who has their number between the number `9 and 5430`.

Help appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL How do you INSERT INTO a table with a SELECT subquery returning multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422529/mysql-how-do-you-insert-into-a-table-with-a-select-subquery-returning-multiple-r)

Comment: Make it between 9 and 15 ,say, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedure in mysql to do this; inside your stored procedure you can use a loop to insert multiple entries. I've provided an example below.

Procedure can be implemented like the code shown here:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure fill_rows(in start_index int,in termination_point int)
begin
    while start_index <= termination_point do
        INSERT INTO `item_owned` (`id`, `uid`, `iid`, `kind`, `time_owned`, `notes`) VALUES (NULL, start_index, '3626', '1', '1592596732', 'NotBanned');
        set start_index := start_index + 1;
    end while;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Now whenever you want to insert uid let's say from range x to y. Assume x = 10 and y = 1000 then you can simply insert this records using this one time procedure call like:

```
call fill_row(10, 1000);
```

This call will insert 990 new rows with uid values 10, 11, 12 ...1000.
Hope this may help you!

Comment: If you have any further doubt you can drop a comment here or if this answer helps you to solve the problem then please mark it as an answer.
Thank you!